# jsp tomcat spring ссылка на изображение

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, jsp, tomcat

Здравствуйте, прощу прощения за очередной вопрос. Прошлый канул в лето т.к я вовремя не ответил. Но проблема у меня осталась, опять убил весь день на это. Суть в том, что jsp не отображает изображение даже по абсолютному пути. Я уже какие пути не пробовал и куда только не клал это изобажение.

Если создать просто html cтраницу с этим адресом, то если открывать через idea ( пкм на странице -> открыть в браузере ) то изображения тоже не будет, но если просто перейти через проводник к этому файлу и отрыть его в браузере, то картинка будет отображаться.

в jsp у меня так ничего и не отображалось, сколько бы я не пытался, только если в webapp/recources закидывать и статичные изображения показывались, которые были во время деплоя там.

Но мне именно и нужно чтоб были на файловой системе изображения, отдельно от сервера, туда они сохраняются через форму и используются.

Так выглядит эта html страница
[image]

это jsp
[image]

Так выглядит jsp после запуска сервера при переходе на неё
[image]

Это ошибка в браузере которая пишется
[image]

Comment: Браузер не даст разрешения так сделать, безопасность все таки.  Если браузеры будут позволять открывать произвольные файлы с компьютера где запущены, то не будет никакой приватности. Исключение есть то что Вы указали, открыв хтмл файл напрямую через проводник.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Хорошо, спасибо, но тогда я вообще не понимаю, как мне сохранять изображения например "аватар" пользователя. Где?

Comment: Вы читали комментарии к предыдущим вопросам?

Comment: @Victor если вы про это, то я не опытен, сглупил что отвечать нужно с уведомлением. Поэтому думал что тема мертвая уже.
 
"Фото должны лежать относительно корня вашего приложения на сервере то есть в той же папке где развернутое приложение. А после ребута сервера видит фотки или нет? Конфигурацию спринга покажите, где вы маппинг ресурсов указываете"

в общем  [вот](https://github.com/newAlastor/AdRealty/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml) 
Маппинг то прописан, но мне же не в resources надо сохранять эти изображения.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать вот так https://toster.ru/q/207493

Comment: @Max файлы пользователей храните в БД, т.е. все данные о пользователях и их файлах будут в одном месте, это будет просто и меньше путаницы.  Если хотите хранить в папке на сервере, то в конфигурации приложения указывайте эту папку, и получайте файлы через отдельный контроллер приложения.

Comment: @MrFylypenko файлы в БД? Первый раз слышу, что за извращение? В БД хранится информация о файле но никак не сам файл!

Comment: @MrFylypenko а можно примерчик, хотя бы небольшой. В web.xml указать путь? А что контроллер должен возвращать? И что тогда в img src указать?

Comment: @Victor пытаюсь так сделать, но у меня проблема другая возникла, в не создается файл "could not be created", при создании файла в ФС. До этого я решал эту проблему переходя в нужную директорию и разрешал доступ для всего. А теперь я просто не понимаю, где он должен сохранить это изображение. Относительно чего?

Answer (score 0):

@Victor хранение картинок в базе - это не извращение, а только один из возможных вариантов. посмотри на OpenCMS - все хранится в базе. и без проблем. Проблема с хранением картинок существует, потому как браузеры не имеют доступа ко всему что не на "сайте" , а хранить картинки в домашней папке сайта - можно, но при этом надо хранить их и в папке разработчика :) чтоб можно было деплоить... и не потерять. вот это  и есть извращение , количество картинок растёт. файл .war будет увеличиваться.
решение этой проблемы существует. необходимо сделать несколько вещей
(только надо учесть что если разворачивать сайт на линуксах - это дно место хранения в файловой системе, а разработка (как правило) идёт под окнами, и место хранения совсем другое.)
в файл context.xml проекта пишем

```
<Context path="/сайт"   allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" >

    <Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
        <PostResources className="MyDirResourceSet" webAppMount="/dataFiles" />
    </Resources>

</Context>
```

в сервлете, в методе

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) {
    .....
     HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
     String url = httpRequest.getRequestURI().replace(сайт+ "/pics", "dataFiles");
     RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        try {
              requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
             } catch (ServletException | IOException ex)
             {
              Logger.getLogger(UserFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
     .....
```

соответственно доступ к таким картинкам будет 
[http://сервер.мой/сайт/pics/подпапки](http://%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80.%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/pics/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

так же надо создать  jar

```
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;

/**
 * Represents a {@link org.apache.catalina.WebResourceSet} based on a directory.
 */
public class MyDirResourceSet extends DirResourceSet {

    protected static final String WinPathToPic = "C:/Catalina/mo/";
    protected static final String DebPathToPic = "/usr/mo/pic/";

    private String getBaseForHostOS() {
        String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (OS.contains("win")) {
            return WinPathToPic;
        }
        return DebPathToPic;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initInternal() throws LifecycleException {
        System.out.println("Base " + getBaseForHostOS());
        setBase(getBaseForHostOS());
        super.initInternal();
    }
}
```

и поместить его в папку lib в расположении tomcat (под линуксами и под окнами).

Сохранять картинки надо с учётом  путей для окон и линуксов, используя примерно это:

```
 private static final String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    protected static final String WIN_PATH_TO_PIC = "C:\\Catalina\\mo\\";
    protected static final String DEBIAN_PATH_TO_PIC = "/usr/mo/pic/";

    public static String getPathToPic() {
        if (OS.contains("win")) {
            return WIN_PATH_TO_PIC;
        }
        return DEBIAN_PATH_TO_PIC;
    }
```

примерно так...
взято из рабочего проекта...

PS
спасибо Alex Kuznetsov с sql.ru

Comment: Спасибо огромное конечно, но мне придется что-то придумывать. У меня spring mvc проект и там даже просто сервлетов нет. и как туда этот фильтор внедрить. Но всё равно, спасибо что-нибудь придумаю, надеюсь.

Comment: @Max  вот тут вроде есть решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928637/how-to-write-a-custom-filter-in-spring-security и тут  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337997/how-to-add-custom-filter-after-user-authorize-in-spring-application